# KDE connect obtrusive notifications

Tags: kubuntu, kde, 20.04, notification, kde-connect

I'm running Kubuntu 20.04 and the notifications from KDE connect are very annoying and obtrusive. Firstly I get repeated notifications from unread messages, every time a new message is received, its notification as well as all the notifications from previous unread messages, stack up in a column and cover-up 20% of the screen on the right side.

Also sometimes the notification boxes glitch and get stuck never clearing up unless manually closed.

Is it possible to display only the latest notification?
And the boxes are also huge, is it possible to decrease their size?
I know there is an option to log to a file/run a script on receiving notifications. Can I use them to somehow send less obtrusive notifications?

Comment: [File a bug](https://bugs.kde.org/)?

Comment: @DKBose There is already a bug reported for this a long time ago (with no response yet). The problem is that KDE Connect will spam the desktop with old notifications from the phone unless you specifically swipe them away on the latter, which I often don't want to do (i.e. prefer to leave some of them to deal with later, but still keep them visible not to forget about them). I would love to use KDE Connect myself, but because of this problem, I cannot.